# How do I move my columns to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to move my columns over to the right in increments until I find the right place for it. When I use padding to move it to the right it crushes my pictures together. I also want to move my pictures closer together using the col-md-4. I searched for an answer but have not found anything relevant to my question. I am still new at this and any help will be great.

```css
header {
  min-height: 110px;
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

.img {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 275px;
  height: 225px;
}

.img_pad {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Take 5 Forms</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Spirax" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Painting website</title>
  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <h1><strong>Guide to Interior House Painting:<br>
            A guide to getting your painting projects done efficiently and quickly!</strong></h1>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row img_pad">

      <div class="col-md-4 img">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="paint_brush3" style="border: 1px solid black; height:215px; width:260px;" alt="No Picture Found">
        </a>
        <p>Click on the image above for a list of links that will get you ideas on some colors.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 img">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="/images/drop_cloth.jpg" alt="125x125" style="height:215px;" alt="No Picture Found">
        </a>
        <p>Click on this picture for some instructions on how to paint your room.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 img">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="/images/paint_brush.jpg" style="height:215px;" alt="No Picture Found">
        </a>
        <p>Click on this picture for a list of items you will need for interior painting.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>
```

Comment: I fixed my problem. I used .img { position: relative; left then the % I wanted;}

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2:**,
i have updated the fiddle.

[Check this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_templates.asp) it have good bootstrap templates which will make your life easy.

Update 1:,
Is this what you asking for?
I added classes `col-sm-6 col-xs-6` for small and extra-small screens.
Ref: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

```css
header {
  min-height: 110px;
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
}

.img_pad {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Take 5 Forms</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Spirax" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Painting website</title>
  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <h1><strong>Guide to Interior House Painting:<br>
            A guide to getting your painting projects done efficiently and quickly!</strong></h1>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row img_pad">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
        <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 img">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634_960_720.png" style="border: 1px solid black; height:215px; width:260px;" alt="No Picture Found">
        </a>
        <p>Click on the image above for a list of links that will get you ideas on some colors.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 img">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634_960_720.png" alt="125x125" style="height:215px;" alt="No Picture Found">
        </a>
        <p>Click on this picture for some instructions on how to paint your room.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 img">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634_960_720.png" style="height:215px;" alt="No Picture Found">
        </a>
        <p>Click on this picture for a list of items you will need for interior painting.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>



</body>
```

Comment: I am looking to move it to the right in small %'s or pixels without it crunching my pictures together. I am going to add a nav bar to the left later as I learn. so I just want to move them at will in small increments.

Comment: Hi Check now. I have added a left side panel which pushes images to right without stretching. Is this what you needed?

Comment: When I replaced your links with my pictures I ended up with an extra column. and the column you have on the left of the pictures is extra won't be there. I won't be able to use it. At this point my 3 pictures are going to be stand alone until I figure out how to do the nav bar on the left. I am thankful for the help. I am still figuring all of this stuff out.

Comment: I fixed my problem. I used { position: relative; left then the % I wanted;}

Comment: Good job. Happy coding :)